# custom branch storage in git

Tags: git

Can I have branches stored in some custom place, such as `refs/custom_heads`? Will not garbage collection treat commits from that branches as garbage?

Are there any convention of where branches should be placed, except `refs/heads`, `refs/remotes` and `refs/tags`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A branch is a "ref" under `refs/heads`. This is how Git identifies a branch. If you try to check out any other sort of ref directly, such as a tag or something under `refs/remotes`, you will detach your `HEAD` and not be on any branch any more.

So, strictly, the answer to your question is no. Branches are exactly those refs which live under `refs/heads`.

You can store "refs" in any other location under the `refs` namespace but it won't be viewed as a branch by Git. Such refs won't be "garbage collected" or cleaned up automatically.

Comment: `Such refs won't be "garbage collected" or cleaned up automatically.` good news :). I could edit fetch configuration to fetch that branches: `fetch = +refs/custom_heads/*:refs/remotes/some_remote_name/*` to fetch that branches